# Laravel 5.2 Update MySQL Database from MongoDB JSON Response

Tags: php, mysql, json, mongodb, laravel

How do i update a table in a MySQL Database from data that I'm pulling from a MongoDB?

I have a function that pulls the data from MongoDB

```
$recordid = '9depnuDz1XHl';

$mongodata = MongoDataPull::find($recordid);
```

When i run the following:

```
return [$mongodata];
```

This is the response i get:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "9depnuDz1XHl",
        "name": "Elliot",
        "surname": "Alderson",
        "email": "elliot@fsociety.com",
        "cell": "01239871234",
        "client": false,
        "payment": false,
        "user_id": "EVhTgHsh1H0A",
        "theme": "default"
    }
]
```

My column names in MySQL are slightly different from the ones from the response.

MySQL Columns in table:

```
fname
lname
email
phone
client
payment
userid
theme
```

Using Eloquent, how would i write a query to update MySQL with the data from MongoDB while mapping to the correct column?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fill()`, make sure to have either `$guarded` or `$fillable` on the model. Also, `find()` will only work if that is the primary ID. Otherwise, use `where('primary_key', "=", $mongodata->_id)->first();`

```
$MysqlModel = Model::find($mongodata->_id);

$MysqlModel->fill(['fname' => $mongodata->name, etc...]);

$MysqlModel->save();
```

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the following error when i use your solution:
`Call to a member function fill() on null`

Comment: Is $mongodata->_id returning a value? Also, is there a Model in your new db corresponding to the id? If you are not updating a record, then you'll want new Model(); $MysqlModel->create([...]);